# Summation Run Time Analysis

Tags: performance, time, sum, analysis

A[] is size of n, B[][] is size of nxn

```
for i_{1,n} {
 for j_{1,n} {
  if(i<=j) -> B[i,j] = sum of the elements A[i], A[i+1],...,A[j]
  else -> B[i,j] = 0
```

I understand that first 2 for loops are n iterations for both.
My question is how to do if(i<=j) part. At max it will sum n number of times (When i = 1 and j = n). At min, it will just do one thing, thus 1.

I'm really really lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm terrible with this theoretical run-time analysis stuff, but this might help to look at things another way:

```
for i_{1,n}
{
    if (j>i) -> B[i,j] = sum of A[i],A[i+1],...,A[j]
    else -> B[i,j] = 0
}
```

Which (I think) happens to be the same as:

```
for i_{1,n}
{
    for j_{1,n}
    {
        B[i,j] = 0
        if (j > i)
        {
            for k_{i,j}
                B[i,j] += A[k];
        }
    }
}
```

That would make it a cubic complexity algorithm. The third loop over `k` executes 0 times, then 1 time, then two times, then three times, and so on up to `n` times. Its upper bound is still `n`. And then we have two more loops with `n` iterations, so our upper bound complexity is `n*n*n` or `O(n^3)`.

Comment: NP -- I was never very good at the theoretical side of CS, but I think it's helpful to write these things out in a verbose way. Then the algorithmic complexity reveals itself through the loops. When you have functions in there like a summation function, it hides those loops and makes things rather confusing.